# How can I fix this View while I´m using a procedure to build it?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I´m creating a database for a class project and I have a problem with it. I have created a view from a table using a function to calculate one of the columns (I need two functions in total but when i have this first one well I will be able to do the second one).

This first code is the function

```
create or replace FUNCTION homepts
RETURN NUMBER
AS
    CURSOR res IS
        SELECT result1, result2, team1, team2 FROM matches;
Pts NUMBER;
res1 NUMBER;
res2 NUMBER;
t1 matches.team1%TYPE;
t2 matches.team2%TYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN res;
    FETCH res INTO res1,res2,t1,t2;
    WHILE res%FOUND LOOP
        IF ((res1)>(res2))then
            Pts := 3;
        ELSE
            Pts := 1;
        END IF;
        FETCH res INTO res1, res2,t1,t2;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE res;
    RETURN Pts;
END;
```

This second code is the view I create using the function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW PRELIGA ("TEAM1", "TEAM2", "RESULT1", "RESULT2", "PTS") AS 
SELECT Team1, Team2, Result1, Result2 FROM matches;
```

Everything is created using oracle sql development. The thing I need is to save every time the Pts variable is changed in their pertinent column. I tried using UPDATE VIEW inside the function but it gives me an error. So if anyone can help me I will be very greatful to him or her.

Comment: I did not quite understand your problem.
but your function looks strange, return type is `varchar2`, but the function returns `number`?

Comment: Thank I change it, but that is not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this is what you need:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW PRELIGA ("TEAM1", "TEAM2", "RESULT1", "RESULT2", "PTS") AS 
SELECT Team1, Team2, Result1, Result2, 
       case when Result1 > Result2 then 3 else 1 end as pts
FROM matches;
```

if you want to use a function, than you shoul rewrite it. e.g.

```
create or replace FUNCTION homepts (pi_result1 in number, pi_result2 in number)
RETURN NUMBER
AS     
BEGIN   
  RETURN case when Result1 > Result2 then 3 else 1 end;
END;
```

so you could use it in your view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW PRELIGA ("TEAM1", "TEAM2", "RESULT1", "RESULT2", "PTS") AS 
SELECT Team1, Team2, Result1, Result2, 
       homepts(Result1,Result2) as pts
FROM matches;
```

Comment: If `Result1` is less than `Result2` then `Team1` gets a point even when they lose. Cool  :-)

Comment: the logic is like in his example. Maybe there are no real losers :)

Comment: Yeah, it works. But the thing is that I have been asked to use functions so if you know any other way to fix it I will be grateful. Anyway I´m very grateful for your help

Comment: @hotfix There are losers and winners. The thing is that when I create the view function only has the last variable it has in the function so there will be always the same for all teams and I don´t know how to save each one of the valor of the variable in the pertinent line of the column

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. I have been trying to do it by myself for a lots of hours. Really thank you